# NodeJS and PHP on same server

Tags: php, node.js, .htaccess, cpanel

I'm having this problem:

I have a nodejs app working on my server at port 1337 and at in the same server i'm working with some PHP files. For example i have the subfolder [www.example.com/subfolder](http://www.example.com/subfolder) which works with PHP, but I have other routes that work with NodeJS.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to access to a PHP subfolder, NodeJS tries to handle it and it says that the route doesn't exist.

The strangest part is that if I restart the server, it works well for a few hours and then it just stops to work properly.

If someone can help i'd be very grateful!!!

I tried to modify several times the htaccess file. Now it looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(subfolder1)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(subfolder2)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(subfolder3)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(subfolder4)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://apuntamelo.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:1337/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:1337/$1 [P,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor 
(Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation 
(https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php8_module>
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10000
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 2000
   php_value max_input_time 3000
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 32M
   php_value post_max_size 50000M
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 50000M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10000
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 200
   php_value max_input_time 300
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 32M
   php_value post_max_size 5000M
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 5000M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: I hate to be pedantic about this, but the subdomain in `www.example.com/subdomain` is `www`. You mean you have a PHP app on a different base path, that is `subdomain`.

Comment: If you have full access to the server, it'll probably be easier and more reliable to write a reverse proxy in the apache config files. Set the paths to redirect to NodeJS and you're done.

Comment: `/subdomain` is a subfolder or route. It's not an actual subdomain. As the first post said, in the URL you gave, `www` is the subdomain. The pattern is `subdomain.domain.suffix`. Anything after the suffix and `/` (and before the `?`) is a subfolder or route. Naming a folder "subdomain" doesn't make it a real subdomain. Since it's just part of your regular site, it's unsurprising that node tries to handle it.

Comment: Subdomain is a subfolder yes!

Comment: Like I said: Write a reverse proxy. That way everything will be handled by Apache and the reverse proxy will pass it on to Node if the path is set as a NodeJS path. Something like `ProxyPass /subfolder http://localhost:1337/` and `ProxyPassReverse /subfolder http://localhost:1337/`. Whenever someone goes to /subfolder, it redirects it to NodeJS. In other cases, it just sticks with Apache / PHP